# JavaScript & HTML - Remove video sounds after exit or escaping the video full screen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, video

I want to remove the sound of the video after I press ESC key or after I exit the video because my video is in full screen.

**Problem **: after I pressed the ESC key or exiting the video full screen the sound is still ongoing, it is a bug, can someone help me with this problem thanks.

I want to stop the video from playing the video sound or stop the sounds of it AFTER I exit the video screen.

here is my video

```
 <video oncontextmenu="return false;" src="../inflightapp/storage/app/public/series_videos/<?php echo ''.$row5['episode_video'].''; ?>" id="<?php echo ''.$row5['id'].'';?>" width="1px" controls controlsList="nodownload"></video>
```

Javascript

```
 var video = document.getElementById(title);   
    document.onkeypress = function(e){
        if((e || window.event).keyCode === 32){
            video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
        }
    };
    $('video.series-video').bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
    var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
    var event = state ? 'FullscreenOn' : 'FullscreenOff';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code,

```
 if (document.addEventListener)
{
    document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler, false);
}

function exitHandler()
{
    if (document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.msFullscreenElement !== null)
    {
        /* Run code for exit */
    }
}
```

Comment: what code should i put in th r`/* Run code for exit*/` and what does your code implied to sir? can u please explain thankss

Comment: okay, and what about my problem sir? what about the sound must be removed after i close the video screen?

Comment: var vid = document.getElementById("Your Video ID");
vid.muted = true;

Comment: im confused rn sir :( can u please refer to my code pleasee. thnaks